# Из-за не правильного htaccess дублируются страницы

Tags: .htaccess

Структура приложения:

```
- app
- public
-- index.php
-- htaccess
- htaccess
```

В корне лежит:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

В директорию public:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Обнаружил что один и тот же контент отображается по разным запросам:

```
http://app.local
http://app.local/public/
http://app.local/public/index.php
```

Подскажите как с этим бороться?

Comment: Папка `public` у вас должна смотреть наружу и являться корнем.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте редирект со скрываемых страниц на ту, которую требуется сделать канонической. Используйте флаг `R=301` (у вас сейчас там только флаг `L`, который  останавливает процесс преобразования и делает текущую ссылку окончательной).